# Return a number instead of NaN in jQuery after using Number()

Tags: jquery

I am currently trying to run a function when that page first loads, and after `products`/`quantities` are clicked, that calculates and displays the total price of what the user has selected.

Everything seems to be going well, but my `price` variable keeps returning `NaN`. Not sure what I'm missing at this point. I did a few searches and `parseInt()` seems to be what I want, but it still returns `NaN`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var bessie = function() {
        //Pull html code for plus/minus qty selector
        var qtyCode = jQuery('.qtyswitcher-qty').html();

        //Pull the current price text that is up on the website
        var bender = jQuery('.price').text();

        //Remove currency symbol and convert price text to a number
        var leela = Number( bender.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));

        //Get value of qty that is currently selected
        var qty = jQuery('#qtyswitcher-clone-qty').attr('value');

        //Number() above was resulting in NaN, so trying parseInt to make it show a number
        var price = parseInt(jQuery(leela).val(), 10);
        /*More stuff that didn't work
        leela.val();
        parseInt(leela);
        */

        //multiply price by qty to get the total for the users current selection
        var total = price * qty;

        //New html that will be inserted into the page
        var newContent = '<p class="multiply">' + '$' + price + '/ea</p>' + '<p class="multiply2">x</p>' + qtyCode + '<p class="multiply3">=</p> <p class="multiply">' + '$' + total + '</p>';

        //New html being inserted
        jQuery(".qtyswitcher-qty").replaceWith(newContent);
    };

    jQuery('.switcher-label').click(bessie);
    jQuery('#qtyswitcher-oneless').click(bessie);
    jQuery('#qtyswitcher-onemore').click(bessie);

    bessie();
});
```

Comment: You would need to show the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
var price = parseInt(jQuery(leela).val(), 10);
// ------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

you're passing a number into `jQuery`, which will make it try to look up thatnumber as a **tag** (like `div`) in the document. It won't find anything, so it'll return an empty set. Calling `.val()` on an empty set gives you `undefined`, which when parsed via `parseInt` becomes `NaN`.

I suspect you don't want to do that, but rather use `leela` directly:

```
var price = parseInt(leela, 10);
```

If you do that, you don't want `Number` on the earlier line:

```
var leela = Number( bender.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
```

Just leave it as a string, which you'll parse in a moment.

---

That said, though, the whole thing seems a bit convoluted. If you have a price, and a quantity, then just:

```
var bessie = function(){
    // Pull html code for plus/minus qty selector
    var qtyCode = jQuery('.qtyswitcher-qty').html();

    // Pull the current price text that is up on the website,
    // removing the currency symbol
    var price = jQuery('.price').text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");

    // Get value of qty that is currently selected
    // NOTE: I'm assuming here that this value can never be blank
    var qty = jQuery('#qtyswitcher-clone-qty').val();

    // Multiply price by qty to get the total for the user's current selection
    // The strings will be coerced to numbers, but if you want to ensure
    // that base 10 is used even if something has a leading 0 or some
    // such, you could use parseFloat here (you presumably don't want
    // parseInt, I can't imagine "price" is a whole number in dollars)
    var total = price * qty;
    // Or: var total = parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty);

    // New html that will be inserted into the page
    var newContent = '<p class="multiply">' + '$' + price + '/ea</p>' + '<p class="multiply2">x</p>' + qtyCode + '<p class="multiply3">=</p> <p class="multiply">' + '$' + total + '</p>';

    //New html being inserted
    jQuery(".qtyswitcher-qty").replaceWith(newContent);
};
```